# Sum rows for one column up that have identical keys based on two other columns and replace other values

Tags: dataframe

it is my first post so do not be too harsh if I make something wrong here.
I am new to the programming language r and got a dataset that has like 4000 rows.

```
 #Data
 Key   Date   Value       ...other columns
 C    2000-04   0.55         name1     x1   <- 
 C    2000-04   0.60         name2     x2   <-
 C    2000-05   1.2
 A    2001-06   4
 A    2001-07   5
 A    2002-08   2
 ...
```

So I figured out that I do have some values for the same Date and same Key using the following code :)

```
 >Data <- as.data.frame(Data)
 >Duplicates <- which(duplicated(Data[c('Key','Date')]),) 
 >View(Duplicates)
```

So I already kind of know where those similar rows based on Key and Date, I want to add up, are.
As my dataset has only 4000 rows I could easily write it into an .csv or excel and add those rows together using my bare hands.

```
 >write.csv(Date, file = ...)
```

But I would like to know how it can be solved using a code.
The only problem I see is that my other columns in that certain row have different names "name1/name2" and "x1/x2".
My new datatable should look like this:

```
 #Data
 Key   Date   Value        ...other columns
 C    2000-04   1.15         name1     x1       <- Add up to 1
 C    2000-05   1.2
 A    2001-06   4
 A    2001-07   5
 A    2002-08   2
 ...
```

So I would like to make out of 2 rows that are similar in key and date one row and put in the other columns of my new row the names/values from my first row.

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly then you can try this -

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 <- df %>%
  group_by(Key, Date) %>%
  mutate(Value = sum(Value)) %>%
  filter(row_number() == 1)
```

**Output is:**

```
> df1
  Key   Date    Value col4  col5 
1 C     2000-04  1.15 name1 x1   
2 C     2000-05  1.2  n     x    
3 A     2001-06  4    n     x    
4 A     2001-07  5    n     x    
5 A     2002-08  2    n     x
```

**Sample data:**

```
df <- structure(list(Key = c("C", "C", "C", "A", "A", "A"), Date = c("2000-04", 
"2000-04", "2000-05", "2001-06", "2001-07", "2002-08"), Value = c(0.55, 
0.6, 1.2, 4, 5, 2), col4 = c("name1", "name2", "n", "n", "n", 
"n"), col5 = c("x1", "x2", "x", "x", "x", "x")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
#  Key    Date Value  col4 col5
#1   C 2000-04  0.55 name1   x1
#2   C 2000-04  0.60 name2   x2
#3   C 2000-05  1.20     n    x
#4   A 2001-06  4.00     n    x
#5   A 2001-07  5.00     n    x
#6   A 2002-08  2.00     n    x
```

Comment: Glad that it helped :)